# How to show values in a tooltip

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tooltip

I've built a network graph and I want to show the information from the data source in my tooltip based on the circle you hover over. Currently, my hover action to turn the circle red works, but my tooltip just shows the same value regardless of where you hover. I'm confused as to where I'm going wrong and how to rectify this. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my code below:

```
  const node = svg.append("g")

    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("r", 0.4)
    .attr("fill", "#f2d974")
    .attr("fill-opacity", 0.4);

simulation.on("tick", () => {
  link
      .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
      .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);

  node
      .attr("cx", d => d.x)
      .attr("cy", d => d.y);
});

var tooltip = d3.select("#france")
.append("div")
.data(nodes)
.style("position", "absolute")
.style("visibility", "visible")
.style("background", "white")
.style("border", "solid")
.style("border-width", "0.5px")
.style("border-radius", "5px")
.style("padding", "5px")
.style("width", "100px")
.style("height", "100px")
.text(d=>d.id)
console.log(d=>d.id)

node
.on("mousemove", function(d){
    console.log(d)
  d3.select(this).style("fill", "red")
  
  tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
    .style("top", (event.pageY))
    .style("left", (event.pageX))
    .text(d=>d.id)
})
.on("mouseout", function(){
    tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are always seeing the same value because you are using the data element from the tooltip:

```
tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
    .style("top", (event.pageY))
    .style("left", (event.pageX))
    .text(d=>d.id) // -> this is the d.id binded to the tooltip
```

Your issue is a shaded variable

Can you try this code and let me know if it works:

```
tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
    .style("top", (event.pageY))
    .style("left", (event.pageX))
    .text(d.id)
```

Comment: My tooltip is now a blank box when I make that change

Comment: I don't know your data, what is the data element binded to the node? does it have an id?

Comment: yh the field that I'm referencing in my data is called id

Comment: on the mousemove event you calling the anonymous `function(d) { console.log(d);...` so you should have acces to the d element. check your console to see if you got for d

Comment: yes I found it in my console.log under it's nested in the mouseevent under __data__ i have my field id in there. how do I get that to show up in tooltip?